# embedding maven, the property ${project.artifact.selectedVersion.majorVersion} does not get resolved after projectBuilder.build()?

Tags: java, maven

My java program embeds the maven 3.0.5 and aether 1.13.1 libraries,
and I use it as follows:

```
ProjectBuildingResult projectBuildingResult =
projectBuilder.build(myArtifact, projectBuildingRequest);
```

all the properties used in the pom file, such as ${spring.version} in here,
get resolved successfully.

```
  <project>
    <groupId>my_group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_artifact1</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
      <spring.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>my_group</groupId>
        <artifactId>my_artifact2</artifactId>
        <version>${project.artifact.selectedVersion.majorVersion}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </project>
```

that is,

```
projectBuildingResult.getProject().getDependencies().get(0).getVersion()
```

returns "3.1.4.RELEASE" instead of "${spring.version}", as expected.

however, the property `${project.artifact.selectedVersion.majorVersion}` does
not get resolved,
so

```
projectBuildingResult.getProject().getDependencies().get(1).getVersion()
```

returns "${project.artifact.selectedVersion.majorVersion}" instead of "2".

why is that?
how to get this resolved?